# Appending 0's to a file in unix/bash if the line is less than a fixed length

Tags: string, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am looking for a way in which to append 0's to the end of multiple lines in a file if they are less than 66 characters in length so that the total line length equals 66.

Here's an example of the file format (... denotes preceding 56 characters):

```
$cat file1
...1234567891
...123456
...
...12345678
```

Ideal format:

```
...1234567891
...1234560000
...0000000000
...1234567800
```

Comment: Two questions: why would you want something like that? and, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Hubert, it is running through a batch suite (requires file of fixed length) and the file I am using is generated off the back of another shell script which I dont have access to at this time to edit.

I have looked about and managed to grab the non 66 length characters through grep '.\{66\}' so speed up but appending zeros, it is combining the looping to add the zero where it I'm struggling having not come from a scripting/unix background :).

I wasn't sure if there was a quick way to do it in bash/unix rather than having to create another script to handle this :)

Thanks, 

Jordan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
$ awk '{s=$0; while(length(s)<66) s=s "0"; print s}' file1
```

or even shorter:

```
$ awk '{while(length<66) $0=$0 "0"}1' file1
```

with provided input:

```
$ awk '{while(length<66) $0=$0 "0"}1' file1
...123456789100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
...123456000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
...000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
...123456780000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Given I am likely to need more practice and upskilling in this, do you have any recommended resources you've used to learn this stuff?
Jordan.

Comment: and google for "Effective AWK programming" by Arnold Robbins

Comment: Thank you for this, Marc :)

Comment: That's a very inefficient approach. Not only are you looping from length(input) to 66 appending one character at a time, the solutions that operate directly on `$0` will cause awk to go through field splitting again (figuring out NF, $1, $2, etc.) every iteration through the loop!

Comment: All very true. Sorry, can't delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Awk** solution:

Sample file `input.txt`:

```
ghWuec]UGaEjxQRN4qUe3uyhNmBszZeJq]0A5hZJiI[fQ[8anRKnpoLXWBwfFt300S
0jmyMPlQbSpFf[ZNdQvR]BwuYxgW6zkBYRPC1PwJEowd7[MmeiWp8Pienu1F32
G]nGbsTdvO24e7Ts5cLRIaYy[zOcUHau5Q7slRYmkcx2LTNR46QE]gs7vKPj
Zxr6HwG15YyYZnDvRDibjOKOlpacrU5oZTWhBixY23]yWfbHe4i6ztME
```

---

The job:

```
awk '{ if(length<66) printf "%s%0*d\n",$0,66-length,0; else print }' input.txt
```

---

The output:

```
ghWuec]UGaEjxQRN4qUe3uyhNmBszZeJq]0A5hZJiI[fQ[8anRKnpoLXWBwfFt300S
0jmyMPlQbSpFf[ZNdQvR]BwuYxgW6zkBYRPC1PwJEowd7[MmeiWp8Pienu1F320000
G]nGbsTdvO24e7Ts5cLRIaYy[zOcUHau5Q7slRYmkcx2LTNR46QE]gs7vKPj000000
Zxr6HwG15YyYZnDvRDibjOKOlpacrU5oZTWhBixY23]yWfbHe4i6ztME0000000000
```

---

The same could be shortened to:

```
awk 'length<66{ printf "%s%0*d\n",$0,66-length,0;next }1' input.txt
```

Comment: Very clever method to do that.

Comment: This is the best and 10x faster ++

Comment: Clearly the right answer. Print the string then print 66 minus length-of-string zeros. Can't get much simpler or more efficient than that! Hope the OP isn't thrown off by the extra code to protect against lines longer than 66.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python one-liner.

**Test data**

```
$ cat test
12345678aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
123

33333333
```

**Python 3**

```
$ python3 -c 'for l in open("test"):print(l.rstrip().ljust(66,"0"))'
12345678aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa00000000000000000000000000000000000
123000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
333333330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Python 2**

```
$ python -c 'for l in open("test"):print l.rstrip().ljust(66,"0")'
12345678aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa00000000000000000000000000000000000
123000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
333333330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

In order to change the actual file, direct the output to a temporary file and override the original in the end:

```
$ python ... > newfile && mv newfile test
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
read line by line
    while (line.length < characterNum + prefixLength)
        line += '0';
    add the line to dynamic array
make a new file with the same name (it will replace the previous one)
write data from array to the new file
```

characterNum is the number of needed characters, in your case 66, prefixLength is 3 in your case("...")

Instead of using dynamic array you can write lines to a new file (with a different name) right after while loop, this will save space.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf $0; for(i=66; i>length; i--){printf "0"} printf "\n"}' file
```

Input:

```
1234567891
123456
123
12345678
```

Output:

```
123456789100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
123456000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
123000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
123456780000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following awk solution too, it will not have any loop into it.

```
awk '{$0=sprintf("%066d",$0);match($0,/0[^(1-9)]*/);print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '{
$0=sprintf("%066d",$0);
match($0,/0[^(1-9)]*/);
print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'   Input_file
```

Let's say following is Input_file:

```
1234567891
123456
12345678
```

Then after running code output will be as follows.

```
123456789100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
123456000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
123456780000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '{
$0=sprintf("%066d",$0);##Re-phrasing current line by adding necessary zeros in front of each line if its length is lesser than 66, %066d will take care of length.
match($0,/0[^(1-9)]*/);##using match for matching regex where it will match from first zero to till a non-zero value comes, so basically it collects all added 0s.
print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)##Now printing the substring of 1st from starting of RLENGTH and another substring which will print from RSTART to RLENGTH, now important thing here is what are RLENGTH and RSTART, these are awk out of the box variables which will be set when a regex match is found from match where RSTART re-presents the first index number of matched regex and RLENGTH re-presents the length of matched regex.
}
' Input_file ## Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Can you show the output and explain how the script works?

Comment: @jas, sorry got busy, was about to add explanation. I just added it, kindly do let me know if any queries/complaints on same. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's possible, but an input line beginning with one or more `0`s will not maintain those zeros in the front of the line.

Comment: yeah I got your point, I just taken OP's sample Input_file as an example and prepared solution then. Removed that . from regex THANKS a ton for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

with `perl`

```
$ # change 13 to whatever length is needed
$ perl -lne 'print $_ . "0" x (13-length)' ip.txt 
...1234567891
...1234560000
...0000000000
...1234567800
```

- `$_` contains current line contents without newline character (because of `-l` option)
- `.` will concatenate the two strings
- `x` is repetition operator, here it will add as many `0`s needed to make line length equal to 13 (lines greater than 13 won't be affected)
- For inplace editing, use `perl -i -lne`

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash

```
printf -v A '0%.s0' {1..66};while read B;do B=$B$A;printf '%.66s\n' $B;done<infile
```