# How to add blank space in the middle of the line if the line is less than fixed length?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I would like to add blank space in the middle of the text file if the length of any line is less than the fixed length(10). The position of blank space is fixed after the 4th character.

File like this:

```
ABCEFGH  K<— length: 10
ABCDE  FGH<- length: 10
ABCD  EFG<- length: 9
ABCDE FGH<- length: 9
ABCDE<-length: 5
```

Desired output:

```
ABCEFGH  K<— length: 10
ABCDE  FGH<- length: 10
ABCD   EFG<- length: 10
ABCD  EFGH<- length: 10
ABCD     E<- length: 10
```

I’m really new to bash. I have tried approach like using awk and sed to append 0 if the line is less than fixed length. It works perfect but what I would like to achieve is to add blank space at given position and so to modify the original file.

I appreciate for any insights!

Approach that I tried:
< [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443750/appending-0s-to-a-file-in-unix-bash-if-the-line-is-less-than-a-fixed-length/46443954>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443750/appending-0s-to-a-file-in-unix-bash-if-the-line-is-less-than-a-fixed-length/46443954%3E)

Updated:

```
awk '{ if(length<10) printf "%s%0*d\n",$0,10-length,0; else print }' test.txt
```

This is the code from the above link that I have tried. As I couldn’t figure out the way to add blank space in the middle, and keep every line in the fixed length, so I couldn’t provide the code for it. I apologise for not providing the code.

Comment: What if the line is less that 3 characters?

Comment: please update the question with the actual code you wrote to add white space; also add the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: The original text file always consists of more than 3 characters in every line.

Comment: consider reviewing [GNU awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html); in particular take a look at the section on the `substr()` function; you'll probably want to print the first 4 characters, a variable number of spaces, and the remaining characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for asking a good question.

`sed` can do this.

```
$: cat tst
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD  EFG
ABCDE FGH
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A



$: sed -E '/^.{1,9}$/{
   / [^ ]/{ s/$/          /; s/^(.{10}).*/\1/; s/^([^ ]*)( +)([^ ]+)( *)/\1\2\4\3/;  }
   /^[^ ]+$/{ s/ //g; s/$/          /; s/^(.{10}).*/\1/; s/^(.*)([^ ])( *)$/\1\3\2/; }
}' tst
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD   EFG    
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD     E
ABC      D
AB       C
A        B
         A
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to update my question, that is, if the length of the line is 5,  5 blank space should be added after 4th character. If it is the case, should I use loop?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk -v tgt=10 'length($0)<tgt{gsub(/ /,""); $0=substr($0,1,4) sprintf("%*s",tgt-length($0),"") substr($0,5)} 1' file
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD   EFG
ABCD  EFGH
ABCD     E
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
$ awk -v l=10 -v i=4 'length($0)>=l{print; next}
                      {
                      gsub(/ /,"")
                      s1=substr($0,1,i)
                      s2=substr($0,i+1,length($0))
                      printf "%s%*s%s\n",s1,l-length($0)," ",s2
                      }' file
```

where `l` is target length and `i` is the insertion point.

Prints:

```
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD   EFG
ABCD  EFGH
ABCD     E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\< '{ split($1,map," "); # Set the field delimiter to < and then split the first field into array map using space as the delimiter
            diff=10-length(map[1])-length(map[2]); # Work out the number of spaces to pad out to.
            printf "%s",map[1]; # Print the first field up to first space
            for (i=1;i<=diff+1;i++) { 
              printf "%s"," " # Loop to the diff count (padding), adding spaces
            } 
            printf "%s",map[2]; # Print the section of the first field after the spaces
            printf "<- length:%s\n","10" 
           }' file
```

One liner:

```
awk -F\< '{ split($1,map," ");diff=10-length(map[1])-length(map[2]);printf "%s",map[1];for (i=1;i<=diff+1;i++) { printf "%s"," " } printf "%s",map[2];printf "<- length:%s\n","10" }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way using `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD  EFG
ABCDE FGH
ABCDE
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10;i+=1){arr[i]=arr[i-1] " "}}{x=10-length($1)-length($2);print $1 arr[x] $2}' file.txt
```

output

```
ABCEFGH  K
ABCDE  FGH
ABCD   EFG
ABCDE  FGH
ABCDE
```

Explanation: firstly in `BEGIN` I prepare `arr` such `arr[1]` is single space, `arr[2]` is two spaces and so on, then for every line I calculate how much space is required by computing 10 minus length of 1st part minus length of 2nd part. Then I print parts concatenated using required number of spaces.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*